# Call to undefined function when called

Tags: php, mysql, function, variables

Here is the error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_page_by_id() in file.php on line 13

Here is the code calling the function:

```
<?php 
require_once("includes/connect.php"); 
include("includes/functions.php"); 
?>
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['info'])){
    $sel_table1 = get_info_by_id($_GET['info']);
    $sel_t2 = 0;
    $table2 = NULL;
} elseif (isset($_GET['page'])){
    $table1 = 0;
    $sel_table1 = NULL;
    $table2 = get_page_by_id($_GET['page']);
} else {
    $table1 = 0;
    $sel_table1 = NULL;
    $table2 = 0;
}

?>
```

And here is my functions.php code for this function:

```
   function get_page_by_id($page_id){
        $query = "SELECT *";
        $query .= " FROM pages ";
        $query .= " WHERE id=" . $page_id;
        $query .= " LIMIT 1";
        $result_set = mysql_query($query);
        confirm_query($result_set);
        if ($page = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)){
        return $page;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
    }
```

I have no idea what to even think lol. This happens when the functions and variables for that function are true.

Thanks

UPDATE: here is my full functions.php:

```
<?php

    function confirm_query($result_set){
        if(!$result_set){
            die("Could not connect to database.");
        }
    }

    function get_all_info(){
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM information ORDER BY position ASC");
        confirm_query($result);
        return $result;
    }
    function get_pages_for_info($information_id){
        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE information_id ={$information_id} ORDER BY position ASC");
        confirm_query($result2);
        return $result2;
    }

    function get_info_by_id($information_id){
        $query = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM information ";
        $query .= "WHERE id=" . $information_id;
        $query .= " LIMIT 1";
        $result_set = mysql_query($query);
        confirm_query($result_set);
        if ($info = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)){
        return $info;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}


    function get_page_by_id($page_id){
        $query = "SELECT *";
        $query .= " FROM pages ";
        $query .= " WHERE id=" . $page_id;
        $query .= " LIMIT 1";
        $result_set = mysql_query($query);
        confirm_query($result_set);
        if ($page = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)){
        return $page;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you confirm that the `functions.php` is actually being included? If you change that to `require` instead of `include`, does the script actually still run? If not, then you're not including the file, so the function never gets defined. You are also vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Yes it is, its at the top of the code i pasted ;) i have other functions running off of functions.php as well. Its only that function that doesnt work. Its not a public script and its nowhere near finished so im not worried about SQLi :P

Comment: Take a look in the server logs. That should be your first action, even before posting on [so]. Most problems will reveal themselves there, and can be resolved quickly.

Comment: you have the include directive, but you're assuming it's actually WORKING. Don't assume. MAKE SURE. change it to require() instead of include().

Comment: Im not assuming, i know it works lol. I changed it to require and the error persists. Ill check my error logs now.

Comment: I'm curious to know what exactly do you think is happening here `if ($page = mysql_fetch_array($result_set))`

Comment: The error message on the log is exactly the same as what is displayed to me which is posted here.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Its returning the first result found otherwise null

Comment: Actually @Chausser it will never return NULL because the if condition is always true; its not comparing anything.

Comment: Its obvious that you don't have a `get_page_by_id` function there; you probably wanted `get_info_by_id`

Comment: i have both. check orignal post :)

Comment: It sounds like you've update A version of functions.php to include the `get_page_by_id` function, but not necessarily THE version in the includes folder that your script is looking in. I know you're confident that you're including the correct version of the file, but it wouldn't hurt to triple check that the version in the includes directory relative to your script is the version you think it is.

Comment: Like deleiftah said, an easy way to check would be to through a die('here'); statement at the top of the file

Comment: Ok, i will triple check and put a die statement to catch where the error is coming from. Might have found the issue tho.

Comment: Actually @BurhanKhalid if mysql_fetch_array returns an empty array it will equate to false and reach the statement as proven here: http://codepad.org/TqOZCCTr

Comment: error_reporting(-1) on the top of codes to see if functions are included

Answer (score 1):

I believe include will only throw a warning and not a fatal error if the file is not found. Try doing:

```
require '/includes/functions.php';
```

This will tell you if the functions file is being included or not.

If the functions file is being included and you are still getting this error is there a syntax error in your functions file before this function?

If no visible syntax error do your error logs have any useful information?

Still nothing then ensure that you are working with the right functions file. Put the following statement at the top of the file:

```
die('here');
```

if you reload the page and do not see the die message you are working with the wrong file.

Comment: Added a couple of other things to look for

Comment: I tried require, error persists. I dont see any syntax errors. Ill post my full functions page in original post, maybe im being blind lol

Comment: what happens if you put the function above get_info_by_id() does it work then?

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_info_by_id() (previously declared in file.php:6) so my functions.php is working.

Comment: I meant to move the entire get_page_by_id() function to be above the get_info_by_id() function in the file. Not to duplicate it